# Where should I ask questions related to networking, routing, Cisco, Juniper, etc.?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I can't find a site designated to networking technologies, such as routers, switches, bridges, firewalls, etc.  I looked all over Stack Exchange sites and [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). **Am I missing something**?

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet is [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). Some tags: [routing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/routing) [switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/switch) [cisco](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cisco) [juniper](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/juniper)

To some extent, some question may be suitable to [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com).